# Como asignar una funcion a un atributo de una clase en python

Tags: python, poo

espero que no sea demasiado "enrredado"

intento crear atributos dinamicos, al mismo tiempo estos utilizarlos en una llamada a otro servicio

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.method = None

    def _call(self, params, options):
        return f"este metodo {self.method} contiene lo siguiente = {params} {options}"


class Methods(Client):
    def __init__(self):

        self.methods = {
            "login_user": "Login_User",
            "add_client": "add_clients_pos",
        }

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # super().__setattr__("client").method = self.methods(name)
        self.method = super().__getattribute__("methods")[name]
        return self._call


metodos = Methods()
a = metodos.login_user("test", "test")
print(a)
```

como pueden ver, heredo la clase de Client, donde tengo el metodo `_call` este metodo lo que hara ese que se conectara a otro servicio pero eso es lo de menos (creo yo), lo que necesito ahi, es setear el atributo `self.method` de la clase Client y poder utilizarlo, para cuando llame a un atributo de la clase Methods este setee el nombre del atributo que estoy ingresando al atributo `self.method` para este posteriormente utilizarlo

he estado dandole vueltas pero me topo con bloqueos, actualmente me da este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cgutierrez/test.py", line 55, in <module>
    a = metodos.login_user("test", "test")
  File "/home/cgutierrez/test.py", line 51, in __getattribute__
    return self._call
  File "/home/cgutierrez/test.py", line 50, in __getattribute__
    self.method = super().__getattribute__("methods")[name]
KeyError: '_call'
```

muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

#### Explicación y una posible solución

Recuerdas que te dije que podías controlar que pasaba cuando accedías a un atributo en Python? Pues te estás topando con un problema que viene con eso.

Gracias a la modificación que hicimos, no se puede acceder a los atributos reales de manera convencional. Tendrás que usar `object.__getattribute__` que (supongo) es la función original que Python usa para acceder a los atributos.

La solución sería usar esta función. A la cual **en este caso particular** también podemos acceder con `super().__getattribute__`

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    # super().__setattr__("client").method = self.methods(name)
    self.method = super().__getattribute__("methods")[name]
    return super().__getattribute__("_call")
```

#### Una mejor solución

Sin embargo, viendo que estás usando un alias para cada función, propongo un cambio de enfoque: usar [`functools.partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod)

partialmethod se comporta como partial, solo que está destinado a ser usado como método de clase. Cito la documentación de partial:

> Retorna un nuevo partial object que cuando sea llamado se comportará
> como func llamado con los argumentos posicionales args y los
> argumentos de palabras clave keywords. Si se suministran más
> argumentos a la llamada, se añaden a args. Si se suministran más
> argumentos de palabras clave, se extienden y anulan las keywords.
> Aproximadamente equivalente a:

```
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

> El partial() se utiliza para la aplicación de funciones parciales que
> «congela» (freezes) alguna porción de los argumentos y/o palabras
> clave de una función dando como resultado un nuevo objeto con una
> firma simplificada. Por ejemplo, partial() puede usarse para crear una
> llamada que se comporte como la función int() donde el argumento base
> tiene un valor por defecto de dos:

```
from functools import partial
basetwo = partial(int, base=2)
basetwo.__doc__ = 'Convert base 2 string to an int.'
basetwo('10010')
```

###### Código

```
from functools import partialmethod

class Client:
    def _call(self, params, options, method):
        return f"este metodo {method} contiene lo siguiente = {params} {options}"

def partial_creator(method):
    return partialmethod(Client._call, method=method)

class Methods(Client):
    login_user = partial_creator("Login_User")
    add_client = partial_creator("add_clients_pos")


metodos = Methods()
a = metodos.login_user("test", "test")
print(a)
```

Lo unico malo de usar partialmethod, es que el argumento method puede cambiarse por lo que el usuario desee, pero simplemente puedes ignorar esto y nunca pasarselo. Si necesitas una solución para ese mismo problema, dime y me encargaré de explicarlo.

Si necesitas una solución distinta, también puedes decirmelo c:

Comment: PD: Perdón por marearte.

Comment: no al contrario, gracias por explicarme, solo que ahi me funciona, si solo mando el metodo pero ahora que intento mandar todo me dice que faltan atributos por mandar :( sinceramente me esta quebrando la cabeza

Comment: Me refería a marearte con mi respuesta a tu otra pregunta. Pero volviendo al tema. Que raro. De casualidad creaste una función _call dentro de Methods?

Comment: haa no sin problemas, ya me funciono de hecho, con eso me voy a quedar, lo que de que manden el methodo, solamente que manden como tal method="algo" de ahi en mas creo que no corre mucho peligro, muchisimas gracias, estos temas estan algo avanzados! y tengo que recurrir a preguntar

Comment: De nada Christian! Suerte con tu proyecto!